# WebApi communication with Identity Server

Tags: identityserver4

I got a simple solution where i am trying to make a call to UserInfoEndpoint from WebApi Server to get more information on user:

- WebAPI Server
- IdentityServer4
- Angular5 frontend

Currently I cannot figure out a way to do this, as UserInfoEndpoint is secured and thus needs authorisation token.

Is there any way i can make a call from WebApi to UserInfoEndpoint to obtain this information?

My current workaround is to load up the JWT Token with all the information, but that is excessive.

Comment: How are you authenticating against IDS. Through the angular app with the javascript client?

Comment: Just standard implicit flow as per identityserver4 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the front end is passing a token to the webapi then you just need to ensure that said token has the correct scopes and then you can use said token to call the UserInfo endpoint as needed.

As for how to extract the token from the current request context, I suspect the best way would be to hook up to a middleware event and store it in HttpContent.Items or suchlike for later use.

Comment: I don't think that is feasable, if done properly (which i hope i have) will mean the access token would only be valid for front end to web api, and  not generically applied. I've also looked into extracting access_token....no luck.

Comment: I think it's the intention of the spec to request the IdentityResources (scopes) for the user info you need as part of the authorize request.The userinfo endpoint will return all the claims that relate to the scopes in the token passed. If you want the API to have special permissions that bypass consent etc then you'd probably have to create your own API and use client credentials to get a new token for that purpose.

Comment: Thats what i am trying to do here, find out way to enable API to communicate to IDS4 without having to rely on frontend making userinfo endpoint calls then passing to API

Comment: The correct (and simplest) way is simply to ask for the correct scopes up front and pass the token through to IDS4 as-is.
That does mean ofcourse that the client itself could also call the UserInfo endpoint directly. If you don't what that to be possible then I guess you'll need to roll your own solution.